# Set the current new document as active document

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

When Word opens, it opens a new, unsaved document. I am working on a Word-AddIn and I need to reference the current document, which may be this new unsaved document. I need to set this new document as the active document. How can I do that?

I have searched for the better part of the day today and have had absolutely no luck. If I open an existing document I can set it as active, but opening a document breaks the process for the user.

```
wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.docx");               
doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
```

I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Document has an Activate() method to make it the ActiveDocument, surely what you are looking for.  The snippet doesn't exactly help to guess that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822131.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Documents class activates the specified document so that it becomes the active document.

```
wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.docx");  
doc.Activate();
```

or if you want to keep a new document as an active one:

```
wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
newDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.docx");  
if(newDoc!=null) 
  newDoc.Activate();
```